# Error - different homepage after login and after logout

Tags: wordpress

Yesterday I was migrating from my "Localhost" to my new Hosting after completing (somewhat) my website.
I was migrating using the "All in one Migrating WP" plugin, and after Restoring my backup everything seemed fine.
Then some users told me that they see another homepage. I went to the website and logout, then I saw that they are right.

Some pictures in order for you to understand what I get:

**At Logon Homepage**
[At Logon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tr9c.png)
**At Logout Homepage**
[At Logout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXywy.png)

Static page is set in settings to my "Elementor", everything looks like my localhost but only after logon of users. What is weirder is that I deleted the "Theme" that the page (after logout) is using, but it is still shown.

I am using Linux (ubuntu 20.04, php8.1-fpm, nginx, redis, mariadb (mysql)) and tried to restart them all after the "All in one migration plugin" did his magic.

I just can't put my hand on this problem.
Thanks for everyone in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** If using "Webinoly" the first thing to do is importing using the migration plugin you use, and then execute `sudo site <your_site_name> -cache=off` and then same again pass the 'on' argument.
restart using systemctl the nginx service.